# How to load and display data from mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to load and display date form mysql, but program show me an error.

**Error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
> on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\index1.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\index1.php on line 20

**Code**

```
<?php
   require_once "connect1.php";

   $polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

   if($polaczenie->connect_errno!=0)
   {
      echo "Error".$polaczenie->connect1_errno. " Opis: ". $polaczenie->connect1_error;
   } else {
      $sql = "SELECT tresc FROM quiz";
      $result = $polaczenie->query($sql);
      while($record = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        echo $record['tresc'];
      }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example similar to how you check if connection is good, also check if query is good.

```
<?php

require_once "connect1.php";

$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

// check if connected
if ($polaczenie->connect_errno != 0) {
    echo "Error".$polaczenie->connect1_errno." Opis: ".$polaczenie->connect1_error;
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT tresc FROM quiz";
    $result = $polaczenie->query($sql);
    // check if query executed properly
    if($result === false) {
        echo "Error ({$polaczenie->errno}) : {$polaczenie->error}";
    } else {
        while ($record = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo $record['tresc'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why -1 then? still was a question about your displayed code, not the query.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli::query` can return false on error which is probably what happened. Check that `$result` is not false before looping through it. If it is there is an error which can be dumped using `$mysqli::error`.

Docs for [mysqli::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Example:

```
 $sql = "SELECT tresc FROM quiz";
 $result = $polaczenie->query($sql);
 if($result) 
 {
     while($record = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
        echo $record['tresc'];
     }
 } 
 else
 { 
    printf("Error: %s\n", $polaczenie->error);
 }
```

Comment: while($record = $result->fetch_assoc())  In this line is error.

Comment: Yes. Because `$result` is false because there is an error in your query. Being "false" you cannot use `fetch_assoc` on it else you get a "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool" error. So before making that call check that `$result` is not false. Uppating answer with example.

Comment: Show any problem in printf("Error: %s\n", $polaczenie->error);